# Type of usage with determiners/phrases

Tags: meaning, phrases

The bride looked radiant, a fairy tale princess.

The bride looked radiant — *fairy tale princess*.

She'd known him all her life, a great friend.

She'd known him all her life — *great friend*.

On these types of structures the phrase won't tag on the end of the sentence without a determiner as is the case with most supplemental phrases. Without the determiner (a,the) you need a dash or a colon.

What is the determiner doing to the phrase so that it can take the comma compared to a phrase that hasn't and needs a em-dash or stronger punctuation?

Comment: I wouldn't say that any of those are fine. The first omits *like* and the second omits *he is* or *he was*. Further, I wouldn't say that the second is fine with a comma, either, since that would make it a comma splice.

Comment: I don't think the versions without the determiner work, whatever the punctuation.

Comment: this first one is a supplement and not a complete sentence (no verb) is it not.

Comment: In both cases an understood phrase is elided. *like* in the first example, *he was* in the second. The versions with the comma are OK in informal contexts, the versions with the em-dash don't work for me at all.